# "Index was outside the bounds of the array" when adding an item to a generic list

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I just had a unique error where a live site was throwing "Index was outside the bounds of the array" on login. I tracked the error down to an old "timing" file inherited from an old project. Here's the full class

```
public class TimingObject
{
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
    public String call { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan duration { get; set; }

    // create a new timing object starting now
    public TimingObject()
    {
        timestamp = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public TimingObject(String call)
    {
        timestamp = DateTime.Now;
        this.call = call;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        List<TimingObject> timings;
        if (HttpContextManager.Current.Cache["PageTimings"] == null)
            timings = new List<TimingObject>();
        else
            timings = HttpContextManager.Current.Cache["PageTimings"] as List<TimingObject>;
        this.duration = (DateTime.Now - this.timestamp);
        timings.Add(this);
        HttpContextManager.Current.Cache["PageTimings"] = timings;
    }
}
```

The error was thrown by `timings.Add(this)`. Why would `Index was out of bounds` be thrown when *adding* an item to a list?

Could this happen if the list is too big? And how big would it have to be exactly?

The code is redundant, and has been removed. But I'd really like to know why this happened.

Comment: Are you *sure* that's the line the error is on?

Comment: The maximum size of a `List<T>` is `int32.MaxValue`, or around two billion one hundred forty seven million. However, because it is an array internally that grows as needed, if you wind up with a size over that value divided by two plus one, if it goes to add another item and needs to increase its size, it might try and add an index larger than it can handle. I'm not exactly sure on the logic there.

Comment: Along with rory and David, I'd be curious to see what it is within the cache. Perhaps it is something else that gets cast as a list.

Answer (score 6):

`List<T>` is not thread safe, and this code looks suspiciously like you would be fetching a shared instance of `List<T>` from multiple threads. I suspect you are adding to the list from two different threads simultaneously and throwing off the array that is making the `List` work under the covers.

Comment: He could use a `ConcurrentBag<TimingObject>` instead or use a lock object to make it thread safe.